# Can search results link to a specific answer, when applicable?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, search, pagination

Searching [for "turtle"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=turtle) gets me a link to [a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta) (without any [highlighting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGi6A.png)) where actually only [one answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19500#19500) contains that search word. Even slightly worse: that answer is on page 2 when sorted on "active". Hence, after clicking the search result, Ctrl/Cmd-F to find the word on the page might get me nothing either.

So: could search results link to an answer *if the search term is only found in one answer of a question*?

Some more background, **please read if you consider upvoting**:

I wonder if the current behavior is by design, as I can imagine one might not want to see multiple search results for multiple posts within the very same question. Maybe linking to answers is exclusively used when specifically searching for answers or a specific user, **and using it depending on search *results* might be confusing**?

As for the current implementation: compare the results when searching for ["if tall is the man"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22if%20tall%20is%20the%20man%22):

[image: Search results linking to question]

...to searching for [inquestion:2349378 "if tall is the man"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=inquestion:2349378%20%22if%20tall%20is%20the%20man%22), [is:answer "if tall is the man"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is:answer%20%22if%20tall%20is%20the%20man%22) and [user:251153 "if tall is the man"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:251153%20%22if%20tall%20is%20the%20man%22):

[image: Search results linking to specific answer, when limiting search within specific question, for specific user, or when only searching for answers]

When using `user:`, search results can also be [both questions and answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:84237%20timeline).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the [new search engine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160100/a-new-search-engine-for-stack-exchange), search results now also link to an answer if the search term is only found in one answer of a question.

Using the search example ["turtle"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=turtle) (given in the question), the results now contains [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19500#19500) too (as mentioned in this feature-request).

[image: Search Results for turtle]

Comment: Indeed, this seams to meanwhile have been solved. I'd mark this "status-completed" if I could, but I guess I'll not bother the moderators with a flag. Thanks!